# Exception in ASP.NET WEB Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a function in an application:

```
private void ds_ItemBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
```

where in this line:

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)(e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked = false;
```

I get an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'.
```

How do I solve this casting error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: pls verify e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0] control type is label or checkbox, you can check it on quick watch e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0] while debugging

Comment: Please provide the DataGrid markup so we can have a better idea of what we are looking at here.

Comment: @JigneshVariya  e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0] is System.Web.UI.LiteralControl

Comment: @JonP the check box markup looks like    <asp:CheckBox ID="lblEditCheck" runat="server" TabIndex="0" Width="30px" CssClass="ColumnHeader" /></td>

Comment: But we are still lacking where it sits in the DataView. Please provide that context in the question itself

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that your first control in the forth column is not a checkbox. I would advise using the [`FindControl` function instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) of your args' `Item` property.

```
private void ds_ItemBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;

    var checkbox = (CheckBox) e.Item.FindControl("lblEditCheck");
    checkbox.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0] is System.Web.UI.LiteralControl . Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might find that you're getting an ItemBound even for the header/footer row or something like that. Added a check to my sample accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However I still get the error, now I get that checkbox variable is null. I still don't get how to resolve the error. The  problem is that I have multiple rows that should be populated in a table, I get only one row + an exception :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `CheckBox` is first in the fourth cell, it looks like there's a `Literal`. Please post fragment of your page code to confirm.